# Interpretation issues with a problem George Polya?

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, word-problem

I have this problem from the textbook "How to solve it

> 10 The vertex of a pyramid opposite the base is called the apex.
>
> (a) Let us call a pyramid “isosceles” if its apex is at the same distance from all vertices of the base. Adopting this definition, prove that the base of an isosceles pyramid is inscribed in a circle the center of which is the foot of the pyramid’s altitude.
>
> (b) Now let us call a pyramid “isosceles” if its apex is at the same (perpendicular) distance from all sides of the base. Adopting this definition (different from the foregoing) prove that the base of an isosceles pyramid is circumscribed about a circle the center of which is the foot of the pyramid’s altitude

I could understand the item a) its easy to understand because we can visualize the distance between the points.

But for the item B) How is the appex vertex (is at the same distance than the sides of the base) because the side of the base is a whole linear, shouldn't it says to the middle point of the side of the base, or what?

This is the solution:

> 10. The base of the pyramid is a polygon with n sides. In the case (a) the n lateral edges of the pyramid are equal; in the case (b) the
>     altitudes (drawn from the apex) of its n lateral faces are equal. If
>     we draw the altitude of the pyramid and join its foot to the n
>     vertices of the base in the case (a), but to the feet of the altitudes
>     of the n lateral faces in the case (b), we obtain, in both cases, n
>     right triangles of which the     altitude (of the pyramid) is a common
>     side: I say that these n right triangles are congruent. In fact the
>     hypotenuse [a lateral edge in the case (a), a lateral altitude in the
>     case (b)] is of the same length in each,     according to the
>     definitions laid down in the proposed problem; we have just mentioned
>     that another side (the altitude of the pyramid) and an angle (the
>     right angle) are common to all. In the n congruent triangles the third
>     sides must also be equal; they are drawn from the same point (the foot
>     of the altitude) in the same plane (the base): they form n radii of a
>     circle which is circumscribed about, or inscribed into, the base of
>     the pyramid, in the cases (a) and (b), respectively. [In the case (b)
>     it remains to show, however, that the n radii mentioned are
>     perpendicular to the respective sides of the base; this follows from a
>     well-known theorem of solid geometry on projections.] It is most
>     remarkable that a plane figure, the isosceles triangle, may have two
>     different analogues in solid geometry

Another item from the solution in this case that I couldn't get was from

> In fact the hypotenuse [a lateral edge in the case (a), a lateral altitude in the case (b)]

Whats mean that the lateral altitude is the hipotenuse, should be either the lateral edge?

Thank you

Comment: It says, the same *perpendicular* distance from all sides of the base. That means, you drop a perpendicular from the apex to each side of the base, and each of those perpendiculars has the same length.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hello Gerry, but that definition is not implied also in (a), because, if we say that the lateral vertex are in the same position from the apex isn't that equal that the perpendicular from the apex is the same lenght for all of the sides like in (b)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what he's talking about:

[image]

In this picture, it might look like the lateral altitude is to the midpoint of the side, but that is just the because this is a very regular pyramid. The side of the pyramid is a triangle. The lateral altitude is the altitude of that triangle: the line from the apex which is perpendicular to the base edge. If the apex were off to one side, the lateral altitude would also be located closer to that side.

Another picture of an oblique pyramid so it is clear that a lateral altitude does not have end in the midpoint of the base.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Paul, a few things. ¿Where its the lateral altitude supposed to end? Because I cannot unsee it from exaclty the midpoint of the side. Another thing if we draw a circle inside the polygon of the base, it supposed to fit correctly, but if we stretch on of the sides, so the base looks like a large rectangle, we couldn't draw a  circumscribed circle right?

Comment: It is suppsoed to end where the perpendicular to the base from the apex meets the line of the base. This can be anywhere. If the pyramid was oblique enough, it could even be outside the pyramid itself - not even lying in the face. I've found a picture with an oblique pyramid (though not as oblique as I just described) to help your imagination. As for your second question, that would not be an isoceles pyramid per definition (b). The lateral altitudes on the short sides of the base would be longer than the lateral altitudes to the long sides of the base.

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now!! But then, why does it say (perpendicular)? I though it refered to the altitud. So can we say that the definition of B is an analog to the definition of A to refer at the same item? Because in (A)  we talk about the same x distance from the apex to the vertexs, and in (B) also x distance from the appex to the shortest way to the sides of the base, but at the end, aren't both definition a couple of n points all at the same distance to the appex?

Comment: The lateral altitude is perpendicular to the base edge - that is, the base of the *triangle*. All altitudes are perpedicular to a base - that is part of what "altitude" means. The altitude of the pyramid itself is perpendicular to the base plane. The lateral altitude is perpendicular to the base of the triangle forming that side. "Isoceles" means lengths are the same, thus both are about certain lengths being the same. But the lengths for each are different, and thus the conditions are different. A pyramid can be (a) without being (b) and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you Paul!